# Samp Error Open Server

Tags: linux

I receive a error in start server samp.

If i write `nohup ./samp03svr &` i receive this error `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'` , and server don't start.
If i write `./samp03` i receive this error : `-bash: ./samp03svr: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

Screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You say that you receive this error message

```
bash: ./samp03svr: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

This means you're trying to run an executable program that has not been compiled for the platform you're using. For example, trying to run x86 code on a Raspberry Pi.

The message from `nohup` isn't an error, it's expected behaviour.

Comment: Or trying to run a 32 bit binary in a 64 bit platform without multiarch support